# Set same cell colour in Excel using VBA, show selection in Theme Colors

Tags: vba, excel

I set cell 1's background colour to `White, background 1, darker 15%` using the colour palette.

[image: colour selection]

Then I use VBA to copy this colour to the next cell:

```
oOutSheet.Cells(1, 2).Interior.Color = oOutSheet.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
```

The colour of the second cell will be the same gray, but not selected in the Theme Colours palette as seen here:

[image: colour selection 2]

Why is the "Theme Colors" item not highlighted as `White, background 1, darker 15%`, and how can I make it be?

Comment: Can i set Theme Color from vba?

Comment: i can set it by ThemeColor  and TintAndShade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If value of `oOutSheet.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ThemeColor = 1 -> 12`
i can set :

```
Dim tint as double
tint=oOutSheet.Cells(1, 1).Interior.TintAndShade 
oOutSheet.Cells(1, 2).Interior.ThemeColor =oOutSheet.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ThemeColor 
oOutSheet.Cells(1, 2).Interior.TintAndShade = tint
```